# How to duplicate a local display over the network with 'seek' and 'speed-changing' feature with GStreamer ?

Tags: gstreamer

I'm using Gstreamer1 for few days. From tutorials, I wrote a C application to playback a file with the following commands :

- play/pause, with gst_element_set_state()
- text overlay, with g_object_set()
- change speed and seek, with gst_element_seek()

`gst_element_seek(data->pipeline, data->rate, GST_FORMAT_TIME, GST_SEEK_FLAG_FLUSH, GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, data->newpos, GST_SEEK_TYPE_SET, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE);`

It works for a local display. The pipeline looks like :

`filesrc location="/myfile.ts" ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! textoverlay ! autovideosink`

Now, I want to broadcast the stream over a local network, with h264/mpeg2-ts (it's a requirement), to duplicate the autovideosink on other PCs, using VLC.

I found an example to reduce the latency ([http://www.z25.org/static/*rd*/videostreaming_intro_plab/](http://www.z25.org/static/_rd_/videostreaming_intro_plab/)). My new pipeline looks like :

```
gst-launch-1.0 filesrc location="/myfile.ts" ! decodebin ! videoconvert ! textoverlay ! tee name="local" 
! queue ! videoconvert ! autovideosink  local. 
! queue ! x264enc biterate=10000 tune=zerolatency byte-stream=true ! h264parse config-interval=1 
! mpegtsmux ! rndbuffersize max=1316 min=1316 ! udpsink host=192.168.1.255 port=5000 async=false
```

Play, Pause, text overlay are OK. But, the seek and the speed-changing do not work : VLC freezes.

With Wireshark, I see that the frames arrive on the distant PC, but they seem different than before the seek.

Helped by wikipedia (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MPEG_transport_stream), I see, for example, that there is no more PMT or PAT frames. As a beginner in video, it's difficult for me to analyse the frames in detail.

I presume gst_element_seek() brakes something in the stream, but I don't find how to resolve this.

Comment: Does `gstreamer udpsrc ...` receiver play the stream?
Not related to the problem: "bitrate", not "biterate".

Comment: I tried with a very simple pipeline (gst-launch-1.0 updsrc port=5000 ! decodebin ! videoautosink). This is the same as VLC.